# Nginx 504 Gateway Timeout Error for Django

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am running a Django site on DigitalOcean using 1ClickInstallation image. Every thing worked fine but I got issue for 504 Gateway Timeout Error. I've tried multiple settings on blogs but not working. Following are my settings:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;

}


server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/django/django_project;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;


    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|woff2|woff|ttf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }



    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/media/;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location static/static-only {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static-only/; 
    }
    # Django static images
    location /static/django_project/images {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static-only/django_project/images/;
    }


    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;

    }
}
```

I followed docs at following link http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

Following is the result of "wget 127.0.0.1:9000"

[image]

but couldn't make sense that where exactly to add directives. Kindly advise.

Comment: Whether the web server receives request? Whether the url for static file work well?

Comment: When I open my homepage it says 
504 Gateway Time-out


nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: You can try: wget http://127.0.0.1:9000 to see whether the web server is running well

Comment: I've added the snapshot in main question...but it gets stuck on awaiting response....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution as I was trying to make changes in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/django-project`. But I needed to add following lines in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` the global settings for Nginx. Lines I've added are:

```
http {
    ...
    proxy_connect_timeout   10;
    proxy_send_timeout      15;
    proxy_read_timeout      20;
}
```

I have a small website hosted and this one above settings are enough. But others may set their settings according to their needs.

Comment: This helped me too. Google developer tool showed me request taking maximum time, I set little more time than maximum time for these parameters.

Answer (score 16):

If you are using **uwsgi** with django, then you might add **uwsgi_read_timeout** directive to nginx's config file at location place

```
location / { 
    uwsgi_read_timeout 120; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm late to the party here but after trying many of these suggestions (and others) I eventually found the timeout for me was occurring from my **DNS** - if you're using **Amazon load balancers** they have an "Idle timeout" set at 120s default.

Comment: And how did you solve this problem? I don't see this config in my AWS Console. Can I configure it using .ebextensions?

Comment: Console -> EC2 -> Load Balancers (left side nav) -> Select Balancer -> Attributes -> increase Idle Timeout